# Add default value to inout parameter using Swfit

Tags: swift, function, default-value, swift3, inout

In Swift 2 it is possible to do the following:

```
class SomeType {
    static let singletonInstance = SomeType()

    func someFunction(var mutableParameter: SomeType = SomeType.singletonInstance) {
        ...
    }
}
```

However in Swift 3 the `var` keyword will be removed for function parameters in favour of `inout`. I have not been able to achieve the same result as the above using the `inout` keyword.

```
class SomeType {
        static let singletonInstance = SomeType()

        func someFunction(inout mutableParameter: SomeType = SomeType.singletonInstance) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Instead I receive an error of "Default argument value of type 'SomeType' cannot be converted to type 'inout SomeType'"

My question is whether it is possible to use `inout` with default value?

Comment: Using `var` in the signature was **not** the same as using `inout`. It just made the argument *locally* variable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164973/var-parameters-are-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-swift-3 should answer your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two keywords you're talking about, `inout` and `var`, are very different.

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID545):

> `In-out` parameters are passed as follows:
>
> 1. When the function is called, the value of the argument is copied.
> 2. In the body of the function, the copy is modified.
> 3. When the function returns, the copy’s value is assigned to the original argument.

Therefore you can't give a default value to an `inout` parameter, as it would make the `inout` property completely useless.

What you can do is receive a normal (constant) parameter **with** a default value, and declare a new `var` with the same name this way (code from the [Swift Evolution's *Removing var from Function Parameters* Proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0003-remove-var-parameters.md), with the addition of the default parameter):

```
func foo(i: Int = 5) {
    var i = i
    // now you can change i as you'd like
}
```

Comment: If the argument `i` exists as a variable outside the function, and you would like the function to update it's value, as well as include a default value... how would you do that?  Is it possible in Swift 3?

Comment: If the variable ``i`` is within the function scope, then you don't need to pass it as a parameter at all! :) Please see example here: http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/58b8e0b2f09a045fe29a515c

Comment: If you must have a default value as well, what about just returning the new value? Example here: http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/58b8e1ccf09a045fe29a515e

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who needs a default `inout` parameter may consider such solution:

```
class SomeType {
    static let singletonInstance = SomeType()

    func someFunction(inout mutableParameter: SomeType) {
        ...
    }

    // Declare function without 'mutableParameter':
    func someFunction() {
        someFunction(SomeType.singletonInstance)
    }
}
```

When you specify the default value for the parameter, the Swift compiler automatically generates a function without the parameter, for you. In this solution we do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a second function signature to "emulate" a default value

```
func foo() {
    var v: Int = 0 // your default value
    foo(bar: &v)
}

func foo(bar: inout Int) {
    // do stuff
}
```