# Converting a constant string to a variable string in Swift

Tags: swift

Consider this hypothetical Swift function:

```
func putFirst(_ string: String) {
    var str = string
    let c = str.popFirst()
    print(c)
}
```

I would expect, based on previous questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164973/var-parameters-are-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-swift-3), that `str` is a variable and thus mutable. However, `str.popFirst()` throws a compile error,

```
Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'str' is immutable
```

Is this a subtlety I'm not aware of? Is it new behavior as of Swift 4? How do I work around it?

Comment: `let c = str.first; str.dropFirst()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [a useless error message](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5515); the problem is that there is only one `popFirst()` method defined on `Collection`. [Here it is](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/b62704bc03e84903448d5e8215a509759a97c519/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift#L1075-L1089):

> ```
> extension Collection where SubSequence == Self {
>   /// Removes and returns the first element of the collection.
>   ///
>   /// - Returns: The first element of the collection if the collection is
>   ///   not empty; otherwise, `nil`.
>   ///
>   /// - Complexity: O(1)
>   @_inlineable
>   public mutating func popFirst() -> Element? {
>     // TODO: swift-3-indexing-model - review the following
>     guard !isEmpty else { return nil }
>     let element = first!
>     self = self[index(after: startIndex)..<endIndex]
>     return element
>   }
> }
> ```

You'll notice that it's constrained such that the `Collection`'s `SubSequence` is itself. This is not true for `String` (as well as many other collection types such as `Array` and `Set`); but it is true for the slices of those types.

There's no unconstrained overload of `popFirst()` on `RangeReplaceableCollection` (which `String` conforms to). The reasoning for this, [as given by Dave Abrahams in this bug report](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5515?focusedCommentId=26982&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-26982), is that `popFirst()` should be O(1); and an implementation on `RangeReplaceableCollection` cannot guarantee that (indeed for `String`, it is linear time).

Another good reason against this, [as mentioned by Leo Dabus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46761165/converting-a-constant-string-to-a-variable-string-in-swift/46761335#comment80468337_46761281), is this is that `popFirst()` doesn't invalidate a collection's indices. An implementation on RRC wouldn't be able to guarantee this.

So therefore because of the wildly different semantics, it's quite reasonable not to expect an overload of `popFirst()` on RRC. You could always define a differently named convenience method on RRC for this though:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection {

  /// Removes and returns the first element of the collection.
  ///
  /// Calling this method may invalidate all saved indices of this
  /// collection. Do not rely on a previously stored index value after
  /// altering a collection with any operation that can change its length.
  ///
  /// - Returns: The first element of the collection if the collection is
  ///   not empty; otherwise, `nil`.
  ///
  /// - Complexity: O(n)
  public mutating func attemptRemoveFirst() -> Element? {
    return isEmpty ? nil : removeFirst()
  }
}
```

You would then say:

```
func putFirst(_ string: String) {
  var str = string
  let c = str.attemptRemoveFirst()
  print(c)
}
```