# Cannot assign through subscript: 'dict' is a 'let' constant

Tags: swift

I have a very simple problem with Swift. 
I created this function:

```
var dictAges : [String: Int] = ["John":40, "Michael":20, "Bob": -16]

func correctAges(dict:[String:Int]) {
     for (name, age) in dict {
          guard age >= 0 else {
          dict[name] = 0
          continue
          }
     }
}
correctAges(dict:dictAges)
```

But I don't understand the error:

> "cannot assign through subscript: 'dict' is a 'let' constant, dict[name] = 0"

How can I solve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36165146/5496433

Comment: Unrelated, but I wouldn't use a `guard` here – a simple `if` would suffice. Or even a `where` clause on the loop: `for (name, age) in dict where age < 0 { ... }`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Input arguments to functions are immutable inside the function body and a Dictionary is a value type, so the `dict` you see inside the function is actually a copy of the original `dictAges`. When you call a function with a value type as its input argument, that input argument is passed by value, not passed by reference, hence inside the function you cannot access the original variable.

Either declare the `dict` input argument as inout or if you'd prefer the more functional approach, return a mutated version of the dictionary from the function.

Functional approach:

```
var dictAges : [String: Int] = ["John":40, "Michael":20, "Bob": -16]

func correctAges(dict:[String:Int])->[String:Int] {
     var mutatedDict = dict
     for (name, age) in mutatedDict {
          guard age >= 0 else {
              mutatedDict[name] = 0
              continue
          }
     }
     return mutatedDict
}
let newDict = correctAges(dict:dictAges) //["Michael": 20, "Bob": 0, "John": 40]
```

Inout version:

```
func correctAges(dict: inout [String:Int]){
    for (name,age) in dict {
        guard age >= 0 else {
            dict[name] = 0
            continue
        }
    }
}

correctAges(dict: &dictAges) //["Michael": 20, "Bob": 0, "John": 40]
```

Comment: Do not use the `inout` version. Functions have a return value for a reason.

Comment: there is golden-rule in Swift: _if the answer is using `inout`, you raised the wrong question_

Comment: @rmaddy I agree, the version with the return value is preferred, but I wanted to show both versions to OP.

Comment: The question specifically asks how to use the modified array, which is what inout is used for

Comment: "Input arguments to functions are immutable inside the function body" Not if they are class instances. A poor explanation.

Comment: @matt, that's not entirely true. Even for reference types, you cannot change the reference itself. You can change a property of the instance, but you cannot change the reference, hence the input argument is immutable. However, I have updated my answer to make it reflect the difference between value and reference types.

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation that you can mutate a dictionary passed into a function is wrong, for the simple reason that a dictionary in Swift is a *value type*. And the types inside the dictionary, String and Int, are values too. This means that, in effect, the parameter `dict` is a *copy* of the original `dictAges`. Nothing that you do to `dict` can have any effect on `dictAges`.

This is a sign that you should rethink your entire architecture. If it was wrong to enter a negative number as an age, you should have caught that up front, as it was being entered. In effect, your entire use of a dictionary of Ints as the model here is probably incorrect. You should have used a dictionary of Person, where Person is a struct with an `age` and a setter that prevents an `age` from being negative in the first place.

If you *must* have a function that runs through an arbitrary dictionary and fixes the values to be nonnegative, make that a feature of dictionaries themselves:

```
var dictAges : [String: Int] = ["John":40, "Michael":20, "Bob": -16]

extension Dictionary where Value : SignedInteger {
    mutating func fixAges() {
        for (k,v) in self {
            if v < 0 {
                self[k] = 0
            }
        }
    }
}

dictAges.fixAges()
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's not good to mutate a sequence as you're looping through it, which is why you only get an immutable copy of the dictionary in your code.

**Swift 4**

I think a nicer approach could be to use `map`, and to take a more functional approach:

```
var dictAges : [String: Int] = ["John":40, "Michael":20, "Bob": -16]

func correctAges(dict:[String:Int]) -> [String:Int]
{
    let corrected = dict.map { (name, age) in age > 0 ? (name, age) : (name, 0) }
    return Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: corrected)
}

dictAges = correctAges(dict: dictAges)
print(dictAges) // ["Michael": 20, "Bob": 0, "John": 40]
```

This way you can reuse this method for any `[String:Int]` dictionary.