# @available rename help needed

Tags: swift, xcode, directive

Not sure about all the ways to use the @rename directive.

I'm trying to rename a method

```
@available(*, deprecated, renamed: "setValueInTable")
public func setValue(table: String, key: String, value: String, autoDeleteAfter: Date? = nil) -> Bool {
```

to:

```
public func setValueInTable(_ table: DBTable, for key: String, to value: String, autoDeleteAfter: Date? = nil) -> Bool
```

Using the directive gives me the warning, but the auto-fix doesn't handle the parameter names. Is there a way to format the directive so the auto-fix works properly for parameter name changes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24452181/2226328 ???

Comment: @Frankenmint That's not a related question. I'm not trying to change values of passed parameters, I'm refactoring the method name and parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Swift doesn't support that right now. My suggestion would be to add a `message` argument to the attribute mentioning the parameter label changes:

```
@available(*, deprecated, renamed: "setValueInTable", message: "The parameter labels have changed to (_:for:to:autoDeleteAfter:)")
public func setValue(table: String, key: String, value: String, autoDeleteAfter: Date? = nil) -> Bool {}
```